# Alfresco: Cannot find many users

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have a problem with Alfresco 4.2.e.

If i try:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/wcs/api/people/testuser
```

I can find all users, no problem.

But if i use:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/wcs/api/people?filter=testuser
```

I can't find many users.

For example i can find user001 in both ways but i can find user002 only with the first solution.

With this problem I am not able to set permissions in Alfresco Share, how can I solve?

Thanks.

EDIT: if I use

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/wcs/api/people?filter=testuser%20[hint%3AuseCQ]
```

It works. SOLVED

Comment: Why do these users match  `testuser`? Is this part of a name?

Comment: No, is the complete name of the user. If i try with "test" the user "testuser" does not appear in any case.